# How to throw an error if firestore document does not exist?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to throw an error if firestore document does not exist?

```
const cancel = (id) => {
  if(window.confirm("Are you sure to cancel this appointment ?")) {
    const userDoc = doc(db, 'accounts', id)
    deleteDoc(userDoc)
  }
}
```

Comment: As of now, it is not possible.Because deleting will not throw exception if the document is not available

Comment: before deleting, I can add if statements but the condition !userDoc.exists doesnt work

Comment: You can check that explicitly. But I think it will cost one read

Answer (score 0):

you can use the condition `if(!userDoc.exist) return ;`·

it doesn't work for because you need to use it this way

```
const cancel = (id) => {
  if(window.confirm("Are you sure to cancel this appointment ?")) {
    const userRef = doc(db, 'accounts', id)
    const userDoc = await userRef.get();
   if(!userDoc.exist) return console.log("throw an error");
    deleteDoc(userRef)
  }
}·
```

Comment: OPs `userDoc` is a `DocumentReference`, which doesn't have an `exists()` method: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference.

Answer (score 0):

Your `userDoc` variable is a reference to a document, it doesn't yet have any data of that document from the database.

If you want to check whether the document exists, you'll first have to [get it from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document). From that link comes this code sample, which is quite close to what you're trying to do:

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF"); //  Create reference
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);   //  Load document data

if (docSnap.exists()) {                 //  Check if it exists
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```